# How to give one my images a click event/ animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I want one of my images, when clicked on, to have the `#app1` animate towards either side then fade out.

I'm aware that my image should have a "on click" attribute, which I have done so. I have a swipe function that will get called. Within my swipe function is where the javascript/jquery is suppose to do the animation.

Yet it is not working, am I doing something wrong? Please help.

THANKS.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- this is comment -->
<html>

<head>

<title>Forget Me Not</title>

<style>

body
{
background-color:#66d9ff;
}

#app1{
position:absolute;
width:250px;
height:250px;
z-index:0;
top:50%;
left:50%;
margin:-150px 0 0 -150px;
background:white;
box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px #888888;
text-align:center
}

img.appIMG1{
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px #888888;
box-shadow:0 0 1px 1px #888888;
}

img.appIMG2{
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px #888888;
box-shadow:0 0 1px 1px #888888;
}

</style>

<script src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

<script>
function Swipe()
{
  $(document).ready(function()
  { 
    $(".appIMG1").click(function()
    {
      $("app1").animate({left:'250px'});
    });
  });
}

</script>

</head>

<body>
<div id="app1"><p><b><u><font face="TimeBurner" color="#66d9ff" size="6">Do you want to make a reminder?</b></u></font></p>
<br>
<img class="appIMG1" border="0" src="YES.png" align="left" hspace=1.8% onclick="Swipe()">
<img class="appIMG2" border="0" src="NO.png" align="right" hspace=2%>
</div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: If you are using jQuery, then having 'onclick' attributes is not the way to go about things.

Comment: Remove the `onclick` attribute, and the function definition around your `$(document).ready`

Comment: A click function inside an onclick function does'nt really sound like a good idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You missed `#`

```
$("#app1").animate({left:'250px'});
```

Demo `-->` http://jsfiddle.net/AdZ9r/

- You don't need on click attribute on your image (*as you are already
  binding click handler with jQuery*)

All you need is (*with removed onClick attribute from `img`*)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".appIMG1").click(function () {
        $("#app1").animate({
            left: '250px'
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: That's not really going to help, though, because then clicking will just set up the function...

Comment: Thanks for answering, this is my first post. 

But it's still not working for some reason...

Comment: this example is exactly what I'm looking for. But for some reason it's still not working. I don't think there is anything wrong with your example and code, so I'm confused as to why it's still not working..

Comment: seem's like you haven't made the changes in your code that i suggested in my answer..Well.. see this fiddle `-->` http://jsfiddle.net/AdZ9r/1/.. make changes in your code as you see in the fiddle.

Comment: Nope, I made the changes in my code. I even copied and pasted the code in the fiddle. Still not working when I click on that image...

Comment: Your code look's fine..Anyway.. do you have any error's on your console (press `f12` to see it on browser)

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined....... startUp.php:44
Failed to load resource...... file:///C:/Users/Nabil/Desktop/start%20up/jquery-1.9.1.js

Comment: Got it...  just replace `<script src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>` with  `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 1):

since you are using the onclick attribute, you can do either this (without the onclick attribute) in the script tag:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{ 
    $(".appIMG1").click(function()
    {
      $("#app1").animate({left:'250px'});
    });
});
```

or this (with onclick attribute)

```
function Swipe()
{
   $("#app1").animate({left:'250px'});
}
```

and don't forget '#' for the app1 selector.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the # in your animate.

Also, you shouldnt need the onClick attached to the IMG if you are using the jQuery events. I cleaned up your JS a bit too.

I created a simple example, based on your code, of what you're looking to accomplish [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5RPmw/)

```
$(".appIMG1").click(function()
{ 
    $("#app1").animate({left:'250px'});
});
```

Comment: the example works as desired, however when I run my code through a browser, it is still not working.